# public custom posts not showing in my wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, php, custom-post-types, plugin-development

I am building a **WordPress plugin** and I want to show all publicly registered custom post types (by theme or other plugins) in my plugin. But it only shows **post and page** custom post types not other publicly registered custom post types like **book, movie**, and so on.

My code:

```
class MyClass
{

    // Boot carbon fields plugin 
    public function lnpa_crb_load()
    {
        Carbon_Fields::boot();
    }

    // Register carbon fields and init submenu page 
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('carbon_fields_register_fields', array($this, 'lnpa_attach_theme_options'));
        add_action('after_setup_theme', array($this, 'lnpa_crb_load'));
        add_action('init', array($this, 'test_get_post_types'), 999);
    }

    public function test_get_post_types()
    {
        $post_types_arr =  array();

        $args = array(
            'public'   => true,
            // '_builtin' => true
        );

        // $post_types = get_post_types($args, 'names', 'and');
        // $post_types = array_diff($post_types, array('page', 'attachment'));
        $output = 'objects'; // Return post type objects
        $operator = 'and';

        $post_types = get_post_types($args, $output, $operator);

        foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
            $post_types_arr[$post_type->name] = ucfirst($post_type->name);
        }

        return $post_types_arr;
    }

    // Declare carbon fields options
    public function lnpa_attach_theme_options()
    {
        Container::make('theme_options', __('AAA Settings', 'text_domain'))

            ->add_fields(array(

                Field::make('select', 'ggg_post_type', __('Select post type.'))
                    ->add_options($this->test_get_post_types())
            ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer (for now), and when you said, "still not working", did you actually mean that your function returns nothing when you call it from within the `lnpa_attach_theme_options()` function? Try doing `var_dump( $this->test_get_post_types() );` or `error_log( var_export( array( __METHOD__, $this->test_get_post_types() ), true ) );` in that function and see what the dump says? But note that, if you're having an issue making it work with a 3rd-party plugin, rather than an issue making `get_post_types()` returns the proper post types, then that's an off-topic question here.

Comment: It returns only 'post', 'page', and 'attachment' post types.

Comment: So this was actually an issue with Carbon Fields, nonetheless, see my new answer and let me know. Also, remember to remove that `add_action('init', array($this, 'test_get_post_types'), 999);` from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not seeing or that your function (`test_get_post_types`) is not returning the custom post types because if you look at the Carbon Fields source code, `carbon_fields_register_fields` is run by `Carbon_Fields\Loader\trigger_fields_register()` which is hooked on `init` with the priority `0`. (See lines [113](https://github.com/htmlburger/carbon-fields/blob/v3.5.3/core/Loader/Loader.php#L113) and [44](https://github.com/htmlburger/carbon-fields/blob/v3.5.3/core/Loader/Loader.php#L44) in `carbon-fields/core/Loader/Loader.php`)

So that means, by the time your `lnpa_attach_theme_options` function runs (i.e. called via the `carbon_fields_register_fields` hook), those custom post types ("book", "movie", etc.) have not yet been registered because despite custom post types are commonly registered during `init`, the priority would not be `0` in normal cases.

Therefore, instead of passing the *output* of your `test_get_post_types` function, you should **pass the function as a [*callable*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) to the `add_options()` function**, like so:

```php
Field::make('select', 'ggg_post_type', __('Select post type.'))
    // Pass a callable, i.e. a function that is called later.
    ->add_options( array( $this, 'test_get_post_types' ) )
```

See the [Carbon Fields documentation](https://docs.carbonfields.net/learn/fields/select.html) for more/other information.

Comment: Thank you, working perfectly.